# What is the ANOVA equivalent of a matched-pairs t-test? MANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, manova, paired-comparisons

I have n subjects. I perform an experiment on all the subjects and measure the outcome in two different ways. I want to evaluate the difference between these two types of measurements. I would use a matched-pairs t-test but I will be adding in a blocking variable.

It seems like ANOVA wouldn't take into account that they are paired.

```
outcome = measureType + blockingVar + measureType*blockingVar
```

Should I use MANOVA where the two types of measurements are the two dependent variables?

Comment: What exactly is a "blocking variable" in this case? Several groups of subjects?

Comment: @amoeba Yes, the blocking variable is a factor with levels that separate the subjects into several groups.

Comment: Then you have a *repeated measures ANOVA* (RM-ANOVA) with one between-subject factor (blockingVar) and one within-subject factor (measureType). It's not a MANOVA.

Comment: That makes sense. So how does RM-ANOVA take into account that measure1 and measure2 should be paired within each subject? For a matched-pairs t-test, I would have to create a new variable that is measure1 - measure2.

Comment: It depends on your software, but usually for the paired t-test you don't subtract the measures manually; you run a paired t-test function and provide both measure1 and measure2 to it.

Comment: Is asking R coding-specific question okay on here? Repeated measures can be hairy with R.

Comment: Asking R coding questions is kinda off-topic, but if it's heavily statistical in nature then sometimes it is tolerated. You can try posting a new question, asking how to code this RM-ANOVA in R, but please provide very clear description of the test you want to run, some of your current attempts (even if unsuccessful) and be sure to check if this perhaps was already asked before.

Comment: (Myself, I am not an R user and cannot help.)